# How to pickle files > 2 GiB by splitting them into smaller fragments

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I have a classifier object that is larger than 2 GiB and I want to pickle it, but I got this:

`cPickle.dump(clf, fo,  protocol = cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

> OverflowError: cannot serialize a string larger than 2 GiB

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704139/pickle-in-python3-doesnt-work-for-large-data-saving) question that has the same problem and it was suggested there to either

1. use *Python 3* protocol 4 - Not acceptable as I need to use *Python 2*
2. use `from pyocser import ocdumps, ocloads` - Not acceptable as I can't use other (non-trivial) modules
3. break the object into bytes and pickle each fragment

Is there a way to do so with my classifier? i.e. turn it into bytes, split, pickle, unpickle, concatenate the bytes, and use the classifier?

---

My code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
import cPickle

def train_clf(X,y,clf_name):
    start_time = time.time()
    # after many tests, this was found to be best classifier
    clf = SVC(C = 0.01, kernel='poly')
    clf.fit(X,y)
    print 'fit done... {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time)
    with open(clf_name, "wb") as fo:
        cPickle.dump(clf, fo,  protocol = cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) 
        # cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL == 2 
        # the error occurs inside the dump method
    return time.time() - start_time
```

after this, I want to unpickle and use:

```
with open(clf_name, 'rb') as fo:
     clf, load_time = cPickle.load(fo), time.time()
```

Comment: Is it SVC from scikit-learn?

Comment: @EliKorvigo yes it is. Added it in the code snippet

Comment: why not using:
from sklearn.externals import joblib;joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')

Comment: @AlokNayak I wasn't familiar with it. It seems better, and I'll try it out now. I'll back in 24 hours (the fit takes forever)

Comment: @AlokNayak Want to add it as an answer and I'll accept if everything goes ok?

Comment: You should use joblib for scikit-learn objects, because it handles numpy arrays separately, unlike pickle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sklearn.external.joblib which automatically split the model file into pickled numpy array files if model size is large

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')
```

**Update:** sklearn will show

> DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.

So use this one instead.

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')
```

which can be unpickled later using:

```
clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

Comment: Or as simple as `import joblib`

Comment: @eli korvigo Joblib (http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) Is this joblib same as 'from sklearn.externals import joblib'? There might be some sklearn specific code modifications I am not sure.

Comment: BTW, I see that only one file was saved during this `joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl')` - is it Ok? shouldn't each numpy array be saved alone?

Comment: @CIsForCookies it's okay, `joblib` saves multiple files if necessary (you can specify a compression level to always save a single file).

Comment: @AlokNayak there is nothing special about serialisation, though they've implemented additional wrappers for other joblib features (most notably, parallelisation).