# Joblib: struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295 when saving large sklearn pipeline object

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am trying to save a large trained sklearn pipeline object using joblib. I would be happy to use any method for saving the model that works, but my research so far hasn't turned up any valid options. The code runs end to end and joblib saves the model perfectly on small datasets, but when I scale it up to use the full dataset, it fails with the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 732, in save_bytes
    self._write_large_bytes(BINBYTES + pack("<I", n), obj)
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

This has been difficult to test because the model takes 2 days to train so I created a synthetic object using the following code, all joblib dumps work fine. This code creates a 25gb object in memory and using vanilla joblib dumps a 6gb file.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
import joblib
import pickle
import time
test = ['A'*1024 for _ in range(0, 1024*1024*1024*3)]

print(sys.getsizeof(test))
try:
    start = time.time()
    joblib.dump(test,'joblib_test1.joblib')
    print("joblib: " + str(time.time()-start))
except:
    pass
try:
    start = time.time()
    joblib.dump(test,'joblib_test2.joblib',protocol=4,compress=3)
    print("joblib protocol 4 compress 3: " + str(time.time()-start))
except:
    pass
try:
    start = time.time()
    joblib.dump(test,'joblib_test3.joblib',protocol=4,compress=9)
    print("joblib protocol 3 compress 9: " + str(time.time()-start))
except:
    pass
try:
    start = time.time()
    joblib.dump(test, 'joblib_test4.joblib.xz')  # xz
    print("joblib xz: " + str(time.time()-start))
except:
    pass
```

[image]

Here is a snippet of the model training code for reference:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([

    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features from subject and body
    ('union', FeatureUnion(  #Feature union merges text, numeric, and categorical data for model ingestion
        transformer_list=[
            ('categorical',Pipeline([  # creates one hot encoded categorical variables
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key=['region'])),
                ('onehotencoder',encoder)
            ])),
            ('numerical',Pipeline([ # selects numeric features
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key=['m_num','a_num','c_num']))
            ])),
            ('bow', Pipeline([ # creates bag of words
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='message')),
                ('clean',CleanText()),
                ('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer)
            ])),
#             Pipeline for pulling ad hoc features from text
            ('text_stats', Pipeline([ # calculates stats from text
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='message')),
                ('stats', TextStats()),  # returns a list of dicts
                ('vect', DictVectorizer())  # list of dicts -> feature matrix
            ]))
        ]
    )),
    ('oversampler',smt),  # Smote: oversample under-represented classes
    ('svd',svd), # Truncated SVD. Used for dimensionality reduction
    ('model', classifier) # Modeling step
],verbose=1)

pipeline.fit(X_train,np.ravel(y_train))

joblib.dump(pipeline,filename,compress=9)
```

Full stack trace for reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training/3_Train_Multiclass.py", line 427, in <module>
    joblib.dump(pipeline,filename,compress=9)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 502, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 819, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 843, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 638, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 295, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 732, in save_bytes
    self._write_large_bytes(BINBYTES + pack("<I", n), obj)
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

Comment: I got the same problem. In my case, it occurred when I set `n_jobs=-1`. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For dumping large files greater than `4GB` size..use pickle protocol `4`.

```
joblib.dump(pipeline, filename, compress=9, protocol=4)
```

Actually problem is with python pickling..as it doesn't work for large saving. This was changed in python 3.4 but you will have to specify `protocol` and since `joblib` basically pickles only. So you have to specify here also. See this question for more details - [_pickle in python3 doesn't work for large data saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704139/pickle-in-python3-doesnt-work-for-large-data-saving)